# What does "if somewhat distrusted" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

And why "*distrust**ed***"?

> Widely reported, **if somewhat distrusted**, accounts by figures like the famous traveler from Venice, Marco Polo, of the willingness of people in China to trade with Europeans and of the immensity of the wealth to be gained by such contact made the idea irresistible.

Comment: **if** in that clause = 'albeit' or 'although' or 'yet'.   The accounts are "widely reported" yet "somewhat distrusted".

Comment: I've answered a similar question once: [Adjective, if adjective: eg “pointed, if fatherly”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/69007/3281)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not easy to answer in a very simple manner as the sentence involves an [absolute construction (clause)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction) which you need to study intensively to understand such a structure. You can visit the link or Google "[participle construction/clause](http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses)" to find helpful links.

The object that people **reported** and **distrusted** is **accounts** (by a person like Marco Polo) as the subject of the main clause is **accounts**. You can rephrase the sentence as follows:

> As **accounts** (by figures like the famous traveler from Venice, Marco
>   Polo, of the willingness of people in China to trade with Europeans
>   and of the immensity of the wealth to be gained by such contact) **were**
>   widely reported, even though **they (accounts)** **were** somewhat **distrusted**,
>   they (accounts) made the idea irresistible.

You will notice that the conjunction **as** and both **subjects** and the **verb *be*** (two were's) are omitted in the sentence as the absolute construction can be a non-finite clause.

The reason "distrusted" is used is that the omitted subject of the clause headed by "if" is **accounts** and the clause is in the passive voice.

Answer (score 1):

The writer is putting together two somewhat different ideas at the same time:

> accounts by ... Marco Polo were widely reported
>
> accounts by ... Marco Polo were somewhat distrusted

When the sentence is written like this, you can see that **distrusted** is acting as a passive participle, hence the **-ed** at the end.

The first idea- that the accounts were widely reported- is easily verifiable by consulting documents from the time. The second idea- that the accounts were somewhat distrusted- is possibly less well documented, and may be the opinion of the writer.

These two ideas are combined using **if**. The intended meaning is similar to  **but**, with the suggestion that the information presented may be unreliable.

> accounts by ... Marco Polo were widely reported, **if** somewhat distrusted.
>
> accounts by ... Marco Polo were widely reported **but possibly** somewhat distrusted.